# How do I add the Debug link on the side of a Fitnesse fixture page?

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm trying to make debugging our Fitnesse tests easier. We're using runnerw.exe for debugging, it works fine. The UserGuide implies there can be a Debug action with the Test, Edit, etc links on the side of the fixture page.

However, there's no Debug action on our fixture pages. Can anyone tell me how to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, changing the buttons on the left hand side involves actually modifying code in FitNesse.  So that is a bit bigger of a deal to do.

However, I can give you a couple of options.

First, you could give everyone a bookmarket that they can use that will run the current page (and set the debug flag).  The following does it :

```
javascript:cur_loc=location.href;location.href=cur_loc + "?test&remote_debug=true";
```

Second, is that you might be able to add the same thing to the PageHeader or PageFooter page, so that it appears everywhere.  But then there will be the issue of the option being there even though you are not on a test page.

```
!-<a href="?test&remote_debug=true';">Run Page in Debug Mode</a>-!
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've got the bookmark solution going and it works fine. But I swear I've seen setups where there's a Debug link on the side, similar to the Test, Edit, Properties, etc links. Anyway, I'll just stick with the bookmark I guess.